# perl ssh move to next if error

Tags: perl, ssh

I have few routers in my network who accept telnet and other few who accept ssh only.
So I used this module (SSH_TELNET::ssh_telnet;)

now there is one router (blys830) not accepting my credential. I want in this situation to try next router and skip current one.

Here is my code but not working.

```
use SSH_TELNET::ssh_telnet;

my @node=("blys830","brtc817");
my @op;
my $ok=1;
$user="xxxx";
chomp $user;
$pass="xxx";
chomp $pass;

foreach $node (@node) {
$node=~s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

$session = SSH_TELNET::ssh_telnet->new("$node") or $ok=0;
$session->login($user,$pass) or $ok=0;

if (!$ok) {
print "not OK\n";
next;
}

else {
$session->cmd('term len 0');
@op=$session->cmd('sh isis neighbor');
}

$session->disconnect;
}
```

I was expecting it to move to next router but it print below output.

```
blys830 TELNET authentication failed at test_ssh.pl line 47
```

Any suggestion ?

Regards
Mahesh

Comment: That module is not public. Anyway, you may like to use `eval` to trap errors. Read the perl documentation.

Comment: Where did you get the module from, does your script terminate after printing this and not progress to the next router at all? if so then most likely the implementation of the module is calling "croak" when it cannot connect which is causing your script to end. As salva said, you can use eval to trap and prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

use eval :

```
use SSH_TELNET::ssh_telnet;

my @node=("blys830","brtc817");
my @op;
my $ok=1;
$user="xxxx";
chomp $user;
$pass="xxx";
chomp $pass;

foreach $node (@node) {
$node=~s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
eval {
$session = SSH_TELNET::ssh_telnet->new("$node") or $ok=0;
$session->login($user,$pass) or $ok=0;
}
if (!$ok) {
print "not OK\n";
next;
}

else {
eval {
$session->cmd('term len 0');
@op=$session->cmd('sh isis neighbor');
}
}

$session->disconnect;
}
```